# Angular 7 Open new tab with querystring

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 7 with Type script.

I need to be able to browse to a component with queryString in a new tab

currently I'm using something like this

const url = myBaseUrl + '\0?param1=123&param2=321' 
window.open(url, '_blank');

and this does browse to the correct page, but when it loads up the queryString has been sanitised so it looks like this 
myBaseUrl/0%3param1%3D123&param2%3D321

which breaks the whole process.

Is there a way to prevent Angular from changing the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one facing a similar issue here is how I fixed my issue.

The problem turned out be caused by our authentication intercepting the URL call and validating the access token. 
Then when the url was passed back in angular it contained a id_token. The URL was intercepted again had the token stripped off and then use the angular router to route the entire URL.

```
this.router.navigate([entireUrl]);
```

This is what caused the query strings to be changed.
I had to check the URL for a ? to indicate it had a query string split it from the main url turn the query string in to an object and use the router to navigate with the query params added correctly

```
if (url.includes('?')) {
    let baseRoute: string = url;
    const splitRoute = baseRoute.split('?');
    baseRoute = splitRoute[0];
    const paramsObj = this.getRouteParamsObject(splitRoute[1]);
    this.router.navigate([baseRoute], {queryParams: paramsObj});
} else {
    this.router.navigate([url]);
}

private getRouteParamsObject(paramString: string): any {
  const pairs = paramString.split('&');
  const result = {};
  pairs.forEach((pair: any) =>  {
      pair = pair.split('=');
      result[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
  });

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

I hope this helps you too. 
Many thanks to Niraj for his help

Comment: How does this enable you to open a new tab with maintaining the querystring?

Answer (score 4):

```js
const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree([myBaseUrl+'/0'], {
      queryParams: {
        params1: "123",
        params2:"321"
      }
  }))
  const newTab = window.open(url, '_blank'); 
  if(newTab) {
      newTab.opener = null;
  }
```

Comment: Please add some more details explaining your code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide it separately like below:

```
this.router.navigate([myBaseUrl + '\0'], { queryParams: { 'param1': 123, 'param2': 321 } });
```

Comment: Hi Niraj, 
That's great, but if I do that it opens the link in the same tab. 
I need this to be in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do like below:

```
this.router.navigate([myBaseUrl + '\0'], { queryParams: { 'param1': 123, 'param2': 321 } }).then(result => {  window.open(link, '_blank'); });
```

Comment: What does `\0` mean?

Comment: @DongBinKim that was for url mentioned in question which is just simple character :)

Comment: I see. Actually, I tried out your answer but where does the `link` come from? I mean, in my test and my thinking, no matter what you provide in the router navigate function, aren't they gone by `window.open`?